# failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied Firebase the user is being created but database is not updating

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is account create activity : Here the user is being created but the unless i change the rules to read write rules to true the database is not getting updated.

I only want the users database who is authorized.
Please help

```
class CreateAccountActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    var mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        idbuttonsignup.setOnClickListener{
            var email = idemail.text.toString().trim()
            var password = idpassword.text.toString().trim()
            var displayName = iddisplayname.text.toString().trim()

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(displayName)){
                createAccount(email,password,displayName)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please fill out all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }


    }



    private fun createAccount(email: String, password: String, displayName: String){
        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener{
                    task: Task<AuthResult> ->

                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    var currentUserID = mAuth!!.currentUser
                    var userID = currentUserID!!.uid
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Task is sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(userID)
                    var userObject = HashMap<String, String>()
                    userObject.put("display_name",displayName)
                    userObject.put("status", "Hello there...")
                    userObject.put("image", "default")
                    userObject.put("thumb_image","default")

                    mDatabase!!.setValue(userObject).addOnCompleteListener{
                            task: Task<Void> ->
                        if(task.isSuccessful){
                            var dashboardIntentOkc = Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java)
                            dashboardIntentOkc.putExtra( "name", displayName)
                            startActivity(dashboardIntentOkc)
                            finish()
                            Toast.makeText(this,"User Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(this,"User Not Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
    }

}
```

---

_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you define the rules in the Firebase Database for read and write operations. Check the Firebase official page if not.

[Get Started with Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: `{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Is it that? Just a doubt, I am new to it. if I do that will the user who has authorization won't gain access to read and write the complete database and modify other users ?

Comment: Yes. They do get the access.

Comment: ah that's not good right? one user should not be able to modify other user data right

Comment: But you can do a user base authentication like in this page. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: By that the particular user can only change his data which matched the particular key.